# Refresh page after last element is displayed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm generating a `<table>` using PHP (I'm taking the values from a MySQL database) then I'm breaking it into smaller tables using this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // Get the table
var table = $('#slideshow > table')
var maxHeight = 600;
// While table is to long
while(table.height() > maxHeight) {
    // Create a new table to append the rows to
    var newTable = $('<table cellspacing="0"></table>');
    // Keep track of the height of this new table
    var newHeight = 0;
    while (true) {
        // Get the first row of the original table
        var row = table.find('tr:first-child');
        if (!row.length) {
            break; // No rows left
        }
        var rowHeight = row.height();
        if (newHeight == 0 || // At least have one row
            newHeight + rowHeight <= maxHeight) // Would fit
        {
            // Update new height
            newHeight += rowHeight;
            // Append row to new table
            newTable.append(row);
        } else {
            // New table is 'full'
            break;
        }
    }
    // Insert newTable before the original table
    table.before(newTable);

}
```

Then I'm using `jQuery Cycle All` script to display them one by one as a slideshow. Is there a way to refresh the page after the last of the tables is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Bad idea. If you refresh the page after all tables are displayed, what will happen? Exactly, the tables will be generated again. And if all tables are displayed, it will reload again.

If you rly want to reload a page with jQuery, try this:

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: I know, but I need it to reload the data from SQL and the script above to calculate again the tables. It will be displayed on a Smart TV, so it is not a problem. I also need a way to know when to call this function, I need some help creating a script that will check when the last of the tables was displayed so I will reload the page.

Comment: Just add the line i wrote to the end of your Script, that should work if i understood your code correctly.

Comment: This script just breaks the table into smaller tables. Then I'm using `jQuery Cycle All` to display them as a slideshow. I need it to refresh after the last is displayed, so I think I should find a way to refresh after the last table is displayed I think. jQuery cycle all displays them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = location.href;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem using this:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        delay: 5000,
        autostop: 1,
        end: function(){
                location.reload();
        }
    });
```

`autostop` must be set to 1 and call a function at the `end`.